# Сложение отрицательных чисел

Tags: информатика, системы-счисления

Подскажите как сложить два отрицательных числа в семеричной системе счисления?
-555(7)+-444(7)

Answer (score 1):

складываешь число так-же как и в десятичной, только делаешь по модулю 7 (вместо 10).

т.е. `-6 + (-5) = -11` по модулю 7 это будет 4 остаток и 1 перенесется в следующий разряд

Answer (score 0):

перевести аргументы в бинарную систему, сложить, и конвертнуть обратно в base7? : )